# VB6 Capturing the Tab Key

Tags: vb6

I am making an exe in vb6 that has forms for the user to fill out. I'm trying to make it so that if you Tab past the visible area of the form, it will automatically scroll down for you if your ActiveControl is not in the visible part of the form. My only problem is that I cannot find a way to capture the Tab keypress. As I understand after much googling, a way to capture the tab key is to set the form's KeyPreview property to True and set the TabStop property to false for every single control on the form.

My question is if there is any way to capture the Tab keypress in vb6 without having to disable all the TabStops.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to look at a different property?

Could reading when the controls "enter" event is fired help you determine to scroll down?
This should occur when the user tabs through each item and could allow you to determine where to scroll your view.

Comment: This isn't an answer, because it does nothing to answer the question. This would make an excellent comment, if you had enough rep to post one. The answer space should not be used to bypass the limited privileges you have at this point. Anything posted as an answer needs to actually be one. The [help] pages have more information.

Comment: This approach (_GotFocus event) is arguably nicer than acting upon the tab key

Comment: @AlexK. Seconded, especially as people may use access keys, or any other method to set focus.

Comment: @KenWhite It answers their problem, but not their stated question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer for you, but it's untested.

Using a timer control, get the active control. Then looking at the form's Top & Height properties, compared with the same of the active control, you can determine if the active control is within the form's viewable area, and if required scroll the form.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can not capture the <kbd>Tab</kbd> press in a VB6 form (using native methods) when there are controls that can get focus.

You can however user other methods like [a timer checking the current control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17227770/588306) or [capturing the `GotFocus` events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226322/588306). These will also handle other ways of getting focus liek access keys or simply mouse clicking.

Comment: I tried both the gotfocus and timer methods and I decided to use the timer method because it doesn't need to be changed with each dynamic controls I am adding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a complete answer to your problem but there are a couple of examples of how to get around this problem on vbforums:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?231180-VB-A-demonstration-of-how-to-trap-the-Tab-key

Answer (score 0):

Programatically scan the controls on the form.

Note the ones that have TabStop=True.

Put them into a list sorted by TabIndex.

Clear the TabStop=True properties of all controls.

Turn on the form's KeyPreview option.

Capture the form's _KeyDown event.

If the key is the tab key, step through the control list to find the next or previous one and set focus to it.

If focus is on a grid, you can optionally move the selected Row/Col forward or backwards.

I wrote this class back in the stone age.  Shamefully ugly code, but it works.

Form with multiple controls plus a grid:

```
Private WithEvents TabStop As cTabStop

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.MSFlexGrid1.Rows = 3
    Me.MSFlexGrid1.Cols = 3
    Me.MSFlexGrid1.FixedRows = 0
    Me.MSFlexGrid1.FixedCols = 0

    Set TabStop = New cTabStop
    TabStop.Setup Me
End Sub

Private Sub TabStop_TabPressed(ByVal Shift As Integer, Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name = Me.MSFlexGrid1.Name Then
        If Shift = 0 Then
            If Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col < Me.MSFlexGrid1.Cols - 1 Then
                Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col = Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col + 1
                Cancel = 1
            ElseIf Me.MSFlexGrid1.Row < Me.MSFlexGrid1.Rows - 1 Then
                Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col = 0
                Me.MSFlexGrid1.Row = Me.MSFlexGrid1.Row + 1
                Cancel = 1
            End If
        Else
            If Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col > 0 Then
                Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col = Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col - 1
                Cancel = 1
            ElseIf Me.MSFlexGrid1.Row > 0 Then
                Me.MSFlexGrid1.Col = Me.MSFlexGrid1.Cols - 1
                Me.MSFlexGrid1.Row = Me.MSFlexGrid1.Row - 1
                Cancel = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Class:

```
Option Explicit
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' This class ATTEMPTS to manage Tab Keypress events
' The specific advantage is the ability capture and cancel a Tab Keypress
'
' This is a horribly inelegant way to get the job done
'
' Bug:
' If a control should be next to receive focus, but is sitting on a control
' which is hidden, the tab order will not be able to proceed past that control.
' i.e. Command1 on Frame1 where Frame1.Visible = False
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Type typeControl
    Control     As Control
    TabIndex    As Long
End Type

Private Type typeSettings
    Controls()      As typeControl
    ControlCount    As Long
End Type

Public Event TabPressed(ByVal Shift As Integer, ByRef Cancel As Integer)

Private Settings As typeSettings
Private WithEvents Form As Form

Public Sub Setup(Form_ As Form)
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "Setup")


    On Error GoTo E

    Dim Control As Control

    ' Get the Form and enable its KeyPreview ability
    Set Form = Form_
    Form.KeyPreview = True

    ' Get the Tab-Able controls from the form
    Settings.ControlCount = 0
    ReDim Settings.Controls(0 To 0)
    For Each Control In Form.Controls
        Call AddControl(Control)
    Next Control

    Exit Sub
E:
    Debug.Print " " & Err.Description
End Sub

Public Sub Clear()
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "Clear")


    Set Form = Nothing
    Settings.ControlCount = 0
    ReDim Settings.Controls(0 To 0)
End Sub

Private Sub AddControl(ByRef Control As Control)
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "AddControl")
    On Error GoTo E
    Dim TabIndex    As Long
    Dim TabStop     As Boolean
    Dim Visible     As Boolean
    Dim Enabled     As Boolean

    ' Only accept controls with these four properties
    TabStop = Control.TabStop
    TabIndex = Control.TabIndex
    Visible = Control.Visible
    Enabled = Control.Enabled

    ' Diable the control's TabStop property
    Control.TabStop = False

    ' Add the control to our list
    Settings.ControlCount = Settings.ControlCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Settings.Controls(0 To Settings.ControlCount - 1)
    Set Settings.Controls(Settings.ControlCount - 1).Control = Control
    Settings.Controls(Settings.ControlCount - 1).TabIndex = TabIndex

    Exit Sub
E:
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "Class_Initialize")


    Clear
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "Class_Terminate")


    Clear
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "Form_KeyDown")


    Dim Cancel As Integer

    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        KeyCode = 0
        RaiseEvent TabPressed(Shift, Cancel)

        Debug.Print " Tab Pressed"

        If Cancel <> 0 Then     ' Tab Keypress Cancelled...
            KeyCode = 0
        ElseIf Shift = 0 Then   ' Tab Pressed...
            TabRight
        ElseIf Shift = 1 Then   ' Shift-Tab Pressed...
            TabLeft
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub TabLeft()
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "TabLeft")


    On Error GoTo E
    Dim CurTabIndex     As Long
    Dim NextControl     As Long
    Dim NextTabIndex    As Long
    Dim c               As Long

    ' Get the Tab Index of the currently active control
    If Not Form.ActiveControl Is Nothing Then ' 2012-09-25 - Jaron
        CurTabIndex = Form.ActiveControl.TabIndex
    End If

    ' Find the control with the next smallest Tab Index
    NextControl = -1
    NextTabIndex = -1
    For c = 0 To Settings.ControlCount - 1
    '        With Settings.Controls(c) ' 2007-05-07
            If Settings.Controls(c).TabIndex >= NextTabIndex And Settings.Controls(c).TabIndex < CurTabIndex Then
                If Settings.Controls(c).Control.Visible And Settings.Controls(c).Control.Enabled Then
                    NextControl = c
                    NextTabIndex = Settings.Controls(c).TabIndex
                End If
            End If
    '        End With
    Next c

    ' Set focus to the next control
    If NextControl >= 0 Then
    '        With Settings.Controls(NextControl).Control ' 2007-05-07
            'Debug.Print " Set Focus to " & Settings.Controls(NextControl).Control.Name
            SetFocusSafe Settings.Controls(NextControl).Control ' 2007-06-05
            DoEvents
    '        End With
    End If

    Exit Sub
E:
    Debug.Print " " & Err.Description
End Sub

Public Sub TabRight()
    Call FunctionTagger("cTabStop", "TabRight")


    On Error GoTo E
    Dim CurTabIndex     As Long
    Dim NextControl     As Long
    Dim NextTabIndex    As Long
    Dim c               As Long

    ' Get the Tab Index of the currently active control
    If Not Form.ActiveControl Is Nothing Then ' 2012-09-25 - Jaron
        CurTabIndex = Form.ActiveControl.TabIndex
    End If

    ' Find the control with the next largest Tab Index
    NextControl = -1
    NextTabIndex = 999999999
    For c = 0 To Settings.ControlCount - 1
    '        With Settings.Controls(c) ' 2007-05-07
            If Settings.Controls(c).TabIndex <= NextTabIndex And Settings.Controls(c).TabIndex > CurTabIndex Then
                If Settings.Controls(c).Control.Visible And Settings.Controls(c).Control.Enabled Then
                    NextControl = c
                    NextTabIndex = Settings.Controls(c).TabIndex
                End If
            End If
    '        End With
    Next c

    ' Set focus to the next control
    If NextControl >= 0 Then
    '        With Settings.Controls(NextControl).Control ' 2007-05-07
            'Debug.Print " Set Focus to " & Settings.Controls(NextControl).Control.Name
            SetFocusSafe Settings.Controls(NextControl).Control ' 2007-06-05
            DoEvents
    '        End With
    End If

    Exit Sub
E:
    Debug.Print " " & Err.Description
End Sub

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub SetFocusSafe(ByRef Control As Control)
    On Error GoTo E
    Control.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
E:
End Sub

Private Sub FunctionTagger(ByVal sModule As String, ByVal sFunction As String)
    Debug.Print " " & Time$ & " " & sModule & "." & sFunction
End Sub

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```